# How to persist the value of counter variable even after button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in below given code when i click the button then count value increases by 1. So in first click count becomes 1. My problem is that when i click again then count again becomes 0. I want that count values persist even when i click the button again. How can i achieve that. should i use declare the count outside the button click event or anything else. How can i get the functionality
that my count variable should persist it's value even after i click the button again.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (minute < 5)
        {
            if (count < 5)
            {
                count++;
                MsgBox("node inserted", this.Page, this);
            }
            else
            {
                MsgBox("not more than 5 nodes in 5 minutes", this.Page, this);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            minute = 0; count = 0;
        }
    }
```

i am using Timer who's interval is 1 minute.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        minute = minute + 1;
    }
```

Please guide me.
thanks.

Comment: Does the following answer solve your question. If it does, you could mark it to be the answer. That may helps others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Since website applications are stateless. You could store it in `ViewState`. For example

```cs
public int ClickCount
{
    get 
    { 
        object o = ViewState["ClickCount"]; 
        return (o == null)? 0 : (int)o;
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState["ClickCount"] = value;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        
     if (minute < 5)
     {
          if (ClickCount < 5)
          {
                ClickCount++;
                MsgBox("node inserted", this.Page, this);
          }
          else
          {
                MsgBox("not more than 5 nodes in 5 minutes", this.Page, this);
          }
     }
     else
     {
          minute = 0; 
          ClickCount = 0;
     }

}
```

Reference: [Control.ViewState Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.viewstate?view=netframework-4.8)